# Error de Missing Styles

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, programación-móvil

Necesito que alguien me ayude: Estoy empezando a aprender a programar en Android Studio y acabo de instalar la versión 2.2.3. Antes tenía la versión 1.3 y todo estaba súper bien hasta que cambié de versión. Cuando abro un proyecto nuevo me sale esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Después de quitarle las dependencias y cuando voy al Activity tengo otro problema:

> "Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout?"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito que me recomienden algo. He buscado pero no he podido arreglarlo.

Comment: leo en los comentarios que ya encontraste la solución. marca como solucionado sobre la respuesta que solucionó tu pregunta para que ayude a otros usuarios con tu problema...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veo que tienes un Tema llamado "Black", te recomiendo selecciones un tema existente, por ejemplo `MainTheme`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ya encontre la solución gracias, ahora no puedo crear una nueva Activity me dice que "Activity name is not set to a valid class name" pero es cualquier nombre que ponga

Comment: Primero ve a Build > Rebuild Proyect y trata de nuevo

Comment: @Yikel200 Si la respuesta de del usuario cnbandicoot o la de Jorgesys ha resuelto tu problema te sugiero que la marques como respuesta y si tienes otra duda crees otra pregunta con tus errores :)

Answer (score 1):

Añade esta dependencia en tu `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
}
```

Comment: gracias, yo he quitado todas las dependencias